# Bayesian Network Problem: What is P(A=T, B=T, C=F, D=F)?

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability, bayesian-network

Suppose you have these probabilities in a bayesian network. What is P(A=T, B=T, C=F, D=F)?

I attempted to answer this by saying that P(A,B,C,D) = P(A) P(B|A) P(C|A,B) P(D|A,B,C), according to the Chain Rule. But it doesn't really seem to work, because D needs to be conditional on E for it to work. So I really need help figuring this out. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Since this is handbook exercise/homework problem please add `[self-study]` tag.

Comment: @Tim This is a problem from a midterm exam which I already took, and I asked my teacher how to get the answer, and he told me, but I forgot what he said. I was preparing for finals and his office hours were over and I couldn't ask him anymore. The finals are already over, but I wouldn't mind knowing the answer to this problem.

Comment: So this is a `[self-study]` kind of question, check the [self-study](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) wiki.

Comment: @Tim Ok, I added the "self-study" tag.

Answer (score 2):

Factorised distribution of the network

```
P(E)* P(A)* P(B|A)* P(C|B)* P(D|B, E)
```

Look at table P(D|B, E) - remove rows inconsistent with evidence, leaving

```
D B E P
F T T 0.8
F T F 0.7
```

You can sum out E my multiplying this by the prior of E

So altogether: read off the other values from the cpt's and multiply out E

```
# P(A=T)* P(B=T|A=T)* P(C=F|B=T)* (P(D=F|B=T, E)*P(E))
     0.6*    0.2*        0.3*     (0.8*0.9 + 0.7*0.1)
#0.02844
```

You can check this using the `gRain` package in `R` which uses the clique tree propagation algorithm (ref)

```
library(gRain)

# define cpt's
tf <- c("T","F")
a <- cptable(~a, values=c(6, 4),levels=tf)
e <- cptable(~e, values=c(9, 1),levels=tf)
b.a <- cptable(~b|a, values=c(2, 8, 4, 6),levels=tf)
c.b <- cptable(~c|b, values=c(7, 3, 95, 5),levels=tf)
d.be <- cptable(~d|e:b, values=c(2, 8, 3, 7, 1, 9, 6, 4),levels=tf)

plist <- compileCPT(list(a, e, b.a, c.b, d.be))

# check tables are input correctly
plist$b
plist$d

# build network
net <- grain(plist)
plot(net)
```

[image]

```
# set evidence
ev <- setEvidence(net, nslist=list(a="T", b="T", c="F", d="F"))

# probability of this evidence
pEvidence(ev)
#[1] 0.02844
```

(ref) Local Computations with Probabilities on Graphical Structures and Their Application to Expert Systems, S. L. Lauritzen and D. J. Spiegelhalter

Comment: Can you dumb this down a little bit? What is a "factorized distribution of the network"? Does that mean it equals P(A,B,C,D,E)?  And why some rows of P(D|B,E) inconsistent with evidence? What does "inconsistent with evidence" mean? Your answer is a little too vague for me (a beginner).

Answer (score 1):

I am very new to graphical models and would love to know how to solve such a problem. Here is my line of thoughts.

The full joint probability is:

$P(A,B,C,D,E)=P(A)P(E)P(B|A)P(C|B)P(D|B,E)$

What is asked for is $P(A,B,C,D)$. To get it, you need to marginalize out E from the full joint probability. Something like this:

$P(A,B,C,D)=P(A)P(B|A)P(C|B)\sum _E P(E)P(D|B,E)$

I don't know if my line of reasoning is correct, and if it is correct, I am not sure what to do with that sum and how to simplify it.